# Simplest possible node.js + nunjucks example

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

Probably will never use node.js nor Nunjucks for any real development, but now for some reason need:

- precompile the some simple templates to javascript with `Nunjucks`
- run the precompiled templates under the `node.js`

I have done:

- installed `node.js` and the `npm` (e.g. have `node` and the `npm` command)
- `mkdir njtest && cd njtest`
- installed the nunjucks with the `npm install nunjucks` (got a `node_modules/nunjucks` directory)
- `mkdir templates`
- in the templates i have created two files `index.html` and `layout.html` with the following `jinja2/nunjucks` content
- `layout.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
        <title>simple example</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Simple example</h1>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

- `index.html`

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
hello world
{% endblock %}
```

- I precomplied the templates with the

```
./node_modules/nunjucks/bin/precompile templates >templates.js
```

and in the `templates.js` I have the precompiled code.

What I should `to do` next to get an running web-server what will use the precompiled `template.js`?

Please, don't search anything advanced behing this question. This is probably an stupid-simple question for someone who know node and javascript.

What i know, will need, create a file let says `app.js` and need run it with the `node` - but what should contain?

```
require 'nunjucks';
```

and probably something like: `var res = nunjucks.render('templates.js');` and what else? (the simplest possible (one time) solution). Note: want use Nunjucks server-side and not in the browser.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Start by initialising your Node application as follows:

```
cd njtest
npm init
```

You can hit "Enter" to accept the defaults for most of the questions, if you're doing this *after* creating app.js then it'll automatically detect this and use it as the entry point for your simple server.

Install Express:

```
npm install express --save
```

Then create `app.js` as follows:

```
var express     = require( 'express' ),
    app         = express(),
    nunjucks    = require( 'nunjucks' ) ;

// Define port to run server on
var port = process.env.PORT || 9000 ;

// Configure Nunjucks
var _templates = process.env.NODE_PATH ? process.env.NODE_PATH + '/templates' : 'templates' ;
nunjucks.configure( _templates, {
    autoescape: true,
    cache: false,
    express: app
} ) ;
// Set Nunjucks as rendering engine for pages with .html suffix
app.engine( 'html', nunjucks.render ) ;
app.set( 'view engine', 'html' ) ;

// Respond to all GET requests by rendering relevant page using Nunjucks
app.get( '/:page', function( req, res ) {
    res.render( req.params.page ) ;
} ) ;

// Start server
app.listen( port ) ;
console.log( 'Listening on port %s...', port ) ;
```

Now fire up a browser, go to http://localhost:9000 and up pops your page!

Hope that helps...

Comment: Minor addition for those really new, also need to `npm install nunjucks --save` if you don't have it installed globally already.

Answer (score 0):

I created simple builder for Nunjucks + SCSS + TypeScript

DOCS: https://github.com/Artik-Man/SamuraiJS

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/samuraijs

```
npm i samuraijs
```

Create `samurai.js` file:

```
import {Samurai} from "samuraijs";

new Samurai({
    paths: {
        source: 'src',
        destination: 'dist'
    }
});
```

Add the following lines to your package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node samurai.js --serve",
    "build": "node samurai.js --build"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Place your *.njk files at the `src/` directory, run

```
npm run serve
```

And open `localhost:3000`

Or `npm run build` to build the project.

Dont think about build configuration. Just code your project!

I hope my builder solves your problem :)